# Error in yaml file to create Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run command to create kubernetes dashboard it throws below error

> kubectl create -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
> error: error parsing
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml:
> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: did not find expected
> document start
>
> I downloaded the yaml file and tried
>
> ERROR: kubectl create -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml error: error
> parsing kubernetes-dashboard.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON:
> yaml: line 25: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Could someone please assist on this?

Comment: Just look at the attached "YAML file content" again. It doesn't look like YAML, does it? Looks like you have downloaded the whole html page instead of particular YAML file, so it's no surprise you failed the validation

Comment: Please take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482875/you-cannot-define-a-mapping-item-when-in-a-sequence-when-running-phpunit-in-sy
Seems like you have invalid yaml starting from:
`rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]`

Comment: @sushma, Can you share your cluster information: `kubectl cluster-info` and kubectl version: `kubectl version` ?

Comment: @mk_sta Please find below details   [kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.61.123:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.61.123:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy]

Comment: **kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:46:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:36:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}**

Comment: I was able to validate this manifest file with the same `kubectl` version. Can you check `kube-system` components health state: `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` ? What tool have you used to bootstrap your cluster? (kubeadm, minikube, etc.)

Comment: have you opened an issue to the repo instead?